# Loop an array get undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to loop an array inside a checkbox group from antd:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Checkbox } from "antd";

function onChange(checkedValues) {
  console.log("checked = ", checkedValues);
}

const a = [
  { label: "Apple", value: "Apple" },
  { label: "Pear", value: "Pear" },
  { label: "Orange", value: "Orange" }
];
const optionsWithDisabled = [
  a.map((i) => ({ label: i.label, value: i.value }))
];

ReactDOM.render(
  <>
    <Checkbox.Group options={optionsWithDisabled} onChange={onChange} />
  </>,
  document.getElementById("container")
);
```

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-group-ant-design-demo-forked-j4tmk?file=/index.js:0-587 
Now i get `Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined` , why?

Comment: Remove the square brackets around `a.map(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Without having had a look at your component or know what it expects for the   `options` prop the below code (yours) will give you a nested array which I don't think you want. That's because [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) will return an array.

```js
const a = [
  { label: "Apple", value: "Apple" },
  { label: "Pear", value: "Pear" },
  { label: "Orange", value: "Orange" }
];
const optionsWithDisabled = [
  a.map((i) => ({ label: i.label, value: i.value }))
];

console.log(optionsWithDisabled)
```

You likely want something like this:

```js
const a = [
  { label: "Apple", value: "Apple" },
  { label: "Pear", value: "Pear" },
  { label: "Orange", value: "Orange" }
];
const optionsWithDisabled = a.map((i) => ({ label: i.label, value: i.value }));

console.log(optionsWithDisabled)
```

And note that:

```
const optionsWithDisabled = a.map((i) => ({ label: i.label, value: i.value }));
```

is the same as:

```
const optionsWithDisabled = a;
```

But I assume you're doing other transformations there